# I want to show the name of the image next to the image itself

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I have another basic javascript question about arrays.

I've got a simple code that loads a random image every time the page loads. The problem is that I want to show the name of the image next to the image itself. I can't seem to figure out how. This is my code so far:

```
//I. Array of pictures that will randomly appear

var plaatjes = new Array ( );
plaatjes[0] = "burger.png";
plaatjes[1] = "tomaat.png";
plaatjes[2] = "aardappel.png";
plaatjes[3] = "sla.png";

//II. function to generate number from 0 to n

function randomplaatje (n)
{
 return ( Math.floor ( Math.random ( )*0.9999999999999999* (n + 1)) );
}

//III. assign any random number from 0 to 2 to x.

x = randomplaatje(3);

//IV. display the image 

document.write('<img alt="randomplaatje" src="' + plaatjes[x] + '"/>');
```

Is it also possible to add alt-tags to the images inside the array? And can they be displayed next to the image in a text-box or something.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use objects inside the array.

```
    var plaatjes = [
      {src:"burger.png","name":"This is a burger"},
      {src:"tomaat.png","name":"This is a tomaat"},
      {src:"aardappel.png","name":"This is a aardappel"},
      {src:"sla.png","name":"This is a sla"}
];

function randomplaatje (n)
{
 return ( Math.floor ( Math.random ( )*0.9999999999999999* (n + 1)) );
}

//Assign any random number from 0 to 2 to x.
x = randomplaatje(3);


// The image source is plaatjes[x].src and the image name is plaatjes[x].name so creating an image with its name next to it could be done this way for instance :

document.write('<img src=' + plaatjes[x].src + '/>');
document.write(plaatjes[x].name);
```

Comment: I tried to use this code but it shows nothing, what did i do wrong? do i need to set empty divs?

Comment: See the above edit by Pierre. Writes the image to the document the same way that your example does.

Answer (score 0):

Your array doesn't have to be just an array of strings, it could be an array of object literals that have both the file name and your alt text:

```
var plaatjes = new Array ( );
plaatjes[0] = {filename: "burger.png", altText: "this is a burger"};
plaatjes[1] = ...
```

And then you can:

```
document.write('<img alt="' + plaatjes[x].altText+ '" src="' + plaatjes[x].filename + '"/>');
```

But megawac's suggestion of creating nodes and appending them is certainly better than using document.write. It gives you much more control over how the DOM gets constructed than using document.write. It's even easier if you use a library like JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

One way to proceed :

Create two divs in your page :

```
<div id="image"></div>
<div id="caption"></div>
```

which will serve as containers respectively for the displayed image and its caption.

Then, in your javascript code, once you've calculated the random index of the image to display, just "populate" your containers, using for instance :

```
document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = '<img alt="randomplaatje" src="' + plaatjes[x] + '"/>';
document.getElementById("caption").innerHTML = plaatjes[x];
```